# java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've an OpenGL application in the Google Play Store and I'm facing a daily exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1085)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1043)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1369)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
```

The problem is, on all my smartphones I cannot reproduce this error. I've already contacted Google for any device info, but they have none (so they say). The platform info in the exception is set to "OTHER".

I found some hints on the net that this error could be from a Samsung Galaxy Y device, and I found some suggestions to include:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in the Android manifest file, but this does not work!

And of course I've the onPause and onResume handling implemented for my GL surface which, if not, produces other eglSwapBuffer problems.

Has anybody a solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I found no solution, I've removed that Samsung Galaxy Y device from the list of supported devices.

Comment: I confirm experiencing the same error on a Samsung Galaxy SIII

Comment: Did you find any solution? This really effects the performance.

Answer (score 11):

*No solution, just comment*

For some reasons I can't comment the previous posts but I've some observations which perhaps could help.

We have the same problem and struggling to find a solution... We drastically reduced the size of our textures and now none is bigger than 1024x900 (don't forget the font ones). But we still need several ones and the problem is still there.
We've pinpoint the problematic devices to the following ones:

```
Samsung Galaxy Y (GT-S5360 GT-S5360B GT-S5360L GT-S5363 GT-S5368 GT-S5369 SCH-I509 SCH-i509)
Samsung Galaxy Y Duos (GT-S6102 GT-S6102B GT-S6102E ivory)
Samsung Galaxy Ace (GT-S5830 GT-S5830B GT-S5830C GT-S5830D GT-S5830G GT-S5830L GT-S5830M GT-S5830T GT-S5830i GT-S5838 GT-S5839i GT-S6358 SCH-I619 SHW-M240S)
Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos (GT-S6802 GT-S6352 GT-S6802B SCH-I579 SCH-I589 SCH-i579 SCH-i589)
Samsung Galaxy Mini (GT-S5570 GT-S5570B GT-S5570I GT-S5570L GT-S5578 SGH-T499 SGH-T499V SGH-T499Y)
Samsung Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300 GT-S5300B GT-S5302 GT-S5302B)
```

Also the error is reported in two flavors with different line numbers:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1099)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1057)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1389)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1138)

java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1085)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1043)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1369)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
```

I don't know if I'm useful here, but in case it helps...

Comment: I updated the list of devices with all the MODEL flavors of each model type.

Comment: got same error in Galaxy SIII, just at different lines:
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1178)
       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1136)
       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1463)
       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)

Comment: I got this from 16 devices and 12 of them are GT-S5830i (Samsung Galaxy Ace).

Comment: Same issue here, same set of devices. I am filtering in Developer Console.

Answer (score 6):

Your memory might be not enough to load all data at first. I met that problem too when making my game with AndEngine, too much Atlas with size bigger than 1024x1024 , data might be broken.

Comment: I've textures up to 2048x1024 pixels which I load at Application startup. So far I do not know which device causes these exceptions because the Samsung Galaxy Y was not the problem, I tested my App on this device successfully. Maybe the only way to get rid of this exception is to filter out the lower end devices.

Answer (score 4):

*No solution, just observations.*

The call to [`eglSwapBuffers` returns false](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java/). The following error handling does not cope with the case that there is no error -- potentially it has not been set by EGL; *OR* the return value is wrong.

I did not find matching sources. These devices either run patched `GLSurfaceView`s (the stack trace search did not find anything...) or they use an in-between version (well, I don't know if 4.0.2 was official, grepcode contains only 4.0.1 and 4.0.3); *OR* I've missed something.

You have to track down which exact devices/android versions run into this problem. Then you could try to workaround this problem by providing a patched `GLSurfaceView` yourself, or using a different EGL config -- provided the problem can be fixed at all. [There are bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25884&q=opengl&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) that are left unhandled for weeks; wondering what greater problems the responsible team faces...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've studied the Android sources too and I came to the same conclusions. In the meantime a user mentioned that he is using this Samsung Galaxy Y device. I've already ordered one for me to be able to test this. But anyway, if the solution for this problem is to write my own GLSurfaceView I'm not happy with it. But thanks anyway for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Manh mentioned that he had the same problem but in his case the memory was not enough. I have ordered and tested my App on this Samsung Galaxy Y which might cause the problem. But on my edition everything works. The only progress could be the recognition, that you shouldn't try to make an App compatible with all devices even with those which obviously make no sense (low resolution screens etc.). Because I think one of those low end devices is causing this problems.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I ended up implementing was to add a global exception handler to catch this error (since it's thrown outside of any thread I have control over).

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {...})
```

So at least the application doesn't crash and I can put up a message explaining the situation.