# java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS report

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have android game, using libgdx framework

on Google Play store there are report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1085)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1043)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1369)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
```

what I can do?

devices reported : Samsung GT-S5830i, Samsung galaxy Y, LGE LG-P990 , Motorola Photon 4G, Motorola Droid X2,

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: nope, it is hepends when GPU memory is full

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL\_SUCCESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459357/java-lang-runtimeexception-eglswapbuffers-failed-egl-success)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has been reported [here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459357/java-lang-runtimeexception-eglswapbuffers-failed-egl-success). There is already [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30191&q=eglswapbuffers&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) filed.

You can help by providing more details to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I made some research and found out that this problem occurs in low end devices because they have low memory. Loading and unloading of textures between two scene crashes SwapBuffer and hence throws this Runtime exception.

Most annoying thing about this issue is that, when I tested in such devices, I didn't get any such error but in playstore I got too many report with this issue.

So, we can tackle this issue in two ways:

1)Filter out low end devices from compatible list.

2)Catch the exception using `UncaughtExceptionHandler()` and tell user about low memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in last edit.**

---

It actually did happen on my low end devices as well (`GT-S5830` and `GT-S5830i`).

The thing is, it did not happen because of low memory; I logged the current memory usage of my game and it did not cross 3 megabytes, when I had like 80 or more megabytes of free ram. I even ran `System.gc()` consistently, which hints the garbage collector to free up some ram space.

I have no workaround but will update this answer as soon as I find one.

---

After some search, gpu related stuff (like textures) are not managed by the garbage collector (that's why they should be disposed manually). So calling `System.gc()` is somehow pointless. Still, I'm disposing all of my textures, and the memory usage of my game is pretty low.

---

I tried all sorts of solutions and nothing worked BUT here is something that should fix the problem (haven't tried this one, but should work nonetheless):

1. Simply don't load so much textures over and over. My game used to dispose and then initialize all textures whenever the user navigated away from a screen. That is possibly causing the problem. What you need to do is to keep the loaded textures/texture atlases in memory (don't lose their reference). That way, navigating back to a screen wouldn't reload all the textures.
2. Avoid using raw `Texture`s and instead use a **POT (Power Of Two)** `TextureAtlas`.

I will apply these two steps to my project, and if the problem goes away, I'll come back to confirm my solution.

---

That wasn't the problem at all. I ran a really long loop of disposing and loading of textures, no exception/error was thrown. My above suggestion is not the solution. The problem is probably related to excessive `Screen` switching, but I guess not since this problem also happens when changing the screen orientation repeatedly from portrait mode to landscape mode and vice versa.

---

### **Solution:**

I thought that `Game`'s `setScreen(screen)` calls `Screen`'s `dispose()` automatically (which is not the case). `dispose()` was used to dispose all of my underlying textures. **I simply solved the problem by calling `dispose()` in `Screen`'s `hide()` overridden method.**

Using `TextureAtlas`s is very important because you reduce the **amount of handles that are attached to each `Texture`**. (Which may be the reason of the EGL_SUCCESS error)

Tested on both `GT-S5830` and `GT-S5830i` (Samsung Galaxy Ace and Samsung Galaxy Y). Problem no longer occurs.