# OpenGL Runtime Exception Issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871261/java-lang-runtimeexception-eglswapbuffers-failed-egl-success-report)

I getting following runtime exeption reports from Google Play Developer Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1085)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1043)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1369)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
```

I never get an exeption like that when i'm developing my game.What can be cause for that?How can i fix this?Everyday someone encounter this problem and it's really frustrating.